# Adding exhaustive dependencies into useEffect and useCallback causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I thought I was getting the hang of these hooks, but the lint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` is tripping me up.

I have this method inside my [Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

```
const onScreenChange = useCallback(
(key, value) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, screenState, { [key]: value });
  localStorage.setItem('screens', JSON.stringify(newState));
  setScreenState(newState);
},
[]); // screenState
```

I'm allowing the rest of my app to access this by passing it into the value prop...

```
return <Provider value={{onScreenChange, ... }}>children</Provider>
```

And then I'm calling this method from a child component when the route changes

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (match.path === `/${screenKey}`) {
     onScreenChange(screenKey, 'external');
   }
}, [onScreenChange, match.path, screenKey]);
```

The above code works exactly how I want, and I can't see this causing any bugs. However eslint is telling me:

`React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'screenState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

When I add `screenState` into the array, it causes an infinite loop as soon as the `onScreenChange` method is called.

It's pretty obvious why the loop is now happening, but how do I stop this and "follow the rules"?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning from eslint seems to be correct. Since screenState value won't be updated correctly if the `onScreenChange` method is called multiple times. You must provide `screenState` as a depedency to `useCallback`

```
const onScreenChange = useCallback(
(key, value) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, screenState, { [key]: value });
  localStorage.setItem('screens', JSON.stringify(newState));
  setScreenState(newState);
},
[screenState]);
```

The other way to write the same code without adding the deps is to make use of state updater callback pattern

```
const onScreenChange = useCallback(
(key, value) => {


  setScreenState(oldState => {
       const newState = Object.assign({}, oldState, { [key]: value });
       localStorage.setItem('screens', JSON.stringify(newState));
       return newState;
  });
},
[]);
```

However you may choose to disable the deps warning if you are absolutely sure what you are trying to do is correct.

You may read below post for more inforamtion:

[How do I fix missing dependency in React Hook useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902)

Comment: Super quick and spot on answer. The state updater callback pattern is exactly what I needed. Didn't know you could do that, but should have guessed really. Thanks so much!